# Loading temporary .csv fails

Tags: r

I'm trying to load a few .csv files that are available on the internet (http**s** url), but keep failing.

**My simple code, which should work:**

```
temp <- tempfile()
url <- "https://iotc.org/sites/default/files/documents/2019/06/IOTC-2018-DATASETS-CESurface.zip"
download.file(url, temp)
```

**I get:**

```
downloaded 0 bytes

Error in download.file(url, temp) : cannot download all files
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, temp) :
  URL 'https://iotc.org/sites/default/files/documents/2019/06/IOTC-2018-DATASETS-CESurface.zip': status was '503 Service Unavailable'
```

This is really weird, because the url works (i.e. the file is downloaded without any issue). Do you have any idea why it doesn't work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked and the site/document is cloudflare protected. So that should be the reason for your issue.

Please check this question for an Answer: [Cannot download file in R - status 503](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728895/cannot-download-file-in-r-status-503)

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks for pointing at the other post!